# Ffmpeg video rotation and center

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor

I was wondering is possible to from 1 video i copy 3 more, then rotate them all by 90 degrees, then move they center with ffmpeg commands? To be clearer what im saying here is picuture what i want to to do: [image]

Comment: Can you illustrate the rotation aspect and then describe what kind of movement you would like?

Comment: @Mulvya first, i want to rotate all 3 videos for 120 degrees, so 1 video will be at 0 degrees, another at 120, another at 270, and last at 360 but that is same as 0 degrees, so when they all are rotated like that, i want to move them, like in the picture to get empty cube in middle of screen surrounded by 4 videos.

Comment: Did you mean 90? The illustration shows orthogonal placement. So, video 1 is 0 degrees, video 2 is 90, video 3 is -90 and video 4 is 0. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah 90, and in middle i need to make a white space to be empty...

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 \
       -filter_complex "[0:v]split=4[a][b][c][d]; \
                        [a]pad=iw+2*ih:iw+2*ih:ih:0:white[base]; \
                        [b]transpose=cclock[br]; \
                        [c]transpose=clock[cr]; \
                        [base][br]overlay=0:w[two]; \
                        [two][cr]overlay=W-w:w[three]; \
                        [three][d]overlay=h:H-h[v]" \
-map "[v]" out.mp4
```

As per your confirmation, I haven't rotated the video at the bottom. In case it had to be rotated 180, use

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 \
       -filter_complex "[0:v]split=4[a][b][c][d]; \
                        [a]pad=iw+2*ih:iw+2*ih:ih:0:white[base]; \
                        [b]transpose=cclock[br]; \
                        [c]transpose=clock[cr]; \
                        [d]hflip,vflip[dr]; \ 
                        [base][br]overlay=0:w[two]; \
                        [two][cr]overlay=W-w:w[three]; \
                        [three][dr]overlay=h:H-h[v]" \
-map "[v]" out.mp4
```

There will be no audio exported with these commands. To preserve audio, insert `-map 0:a -c:a copy`